# How to manipulate a view state data in web application?

Tags: security, testing, penetration-testing

I am testing a web application which is an attendance submitting page.  The functionality is that if two users happen to update same student attendance we shall display a warning of the change with the latest change.

For this Developers have implemented some logic like they will save the value that we enter in text box which are not yet saved in view state.They will be comparing values of view state, current data and database data and display the latest change.

As part of testing, I would like to know is there anyway so that I can modify/hack the data that developer store in view state.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using javascript, You can access the Hidden field "__ViewState" through JavaScript but it is all encrypted. You can only see the encrypted values.

Even if you change it through javascript, server side it will check if the data is tampered.

You can decrypt and see viewstate using below code. For this to work the ViewState must be set as not encrypted [More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479501.aspx)

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64Strin‌​g(txtViewState.Text)‌​);
```

But tampering viewstate is not quite possible since `EnableViewStateMac` property is `true` by default in ASP.NET 
[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728106/how-to-detect-viewstate-is-tamper-or-not-programatically)

Comment: That means I have no option to catch this data right

Comment: You will be able to decrypt and see the data [More Information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638671/is-it-possible-to-decrypt-and-view-viewstate-values). But tampering is not quite possible if the server side  settings are more tight. [More Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728106/how-to-detect-viewstate-is-tamper-or-not-programatically) Mark it as answered if this answer your question